# Using usercontrols with static resources from external assembly

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, staticresource

It sounds very simple and it's killing me!

I'm trying to use one usercontrol with styles from a ResourceDictionary of an external assembly, but I get an exception at runtime.

Here is how to reproduce:

1. Create a silverlight class library called MyControls.dll
2. Create an usercontrol called SuperControl:

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="MyControls;component/Styles.xaml" x:Key="Styles" />
   </UserControl.Resources>


   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
       <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Text="Hello"/>
   </Grid>
   ```
3. Create a Styles.xaml ResourceDictionary and add:

   ```
   <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
       <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
       <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
       <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,0,4"/>
       <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
   </Style>
   ```
4. Create a Silverlight Application Called SL and add Mycontrols as reference
5. In MainPage.xaml Grid, add:

   ```
   <MyControls:SuperControl />
   ```
6. It will compile, but running the application you get "Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source'. [Line: 10 Position: 36]"
7. I added this to the application's App.xaml

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyControls;component/Styles.xaml" />
   ```
8. Same error... :(

Any thoughts?

Comment: I had a similar problem and the cause was using a backslash (\) instead of forward slash (/) when referencing the file.  The xaml parser in VS was able to resolve the location, but at run time an error was being generated. Hopefully this will help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Step 2.
You forgot /.

> Source="MyControls;component/Styles.xaml"

Write

> Source="/MyControls;component/Styles.xaml"